Will moving Windows VM's from VMware ESXi to RH9 KVM cause Windows activation?
We are planning to migrate away from VMware ESXi for our company servers.  We have a LOT of Windows virtual machines used for testing (different configurations, combinations of options, etc) in our test lab.  These include Windows 10 and Windows Server 2019 VM's.
I want to ensure that all of our test VM's don't trigger activation when Windows detects the hardware signature has changed, as I suspect would happen when moving to a new hypervisor.
We are considering what hypervisor to move to next, and we like the Red Hat 9's KVM.
Does anyone have experience with this migration?
Do your Windows VM's require activation after moving?
Please note that our test lab containing the VM's is air-gapped, and must never connect to the Internet.
So don't suggest 'just reactivate'...not an option.

It likely would require activation, otherwise a virtual could be moved anywhere. Microsoft doesn't publish all of the information required for activation, only some criteria and "other" information about the device.

This should be question asked to MS support, not here.

We have already spoken with MS, and they say that switching hypervisors may cause reactivation.  And they are happy to reactivate each machine.  Useless.  I'm interested in how/if anyone has preserved their activation on switching hypervisors.

Many organizations have a security regime. That doesn't prevent them from using a simple proxy to activate Windows, using the free KMS activation service proxy... All Windows require activation. They either use KMS or call on the phone and activate. Every installation of Windows on planet Earth has been that way for 20+ years...This isn't Windows XP where the instructor puts a key on the chalkboard.

You will absolutely need to do that. Even a moderate hardware change triggers the need in Windows re-activation.
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/reactivating-windows-after-a-hardware-change-2c0e962a-f04c-145b-6ead-fb3fc72b6665

I'm not happy with the answer...but I guess unavoidable.  That's a lot of manual activations...if anyone has found a workaround for deactivation moving to RH9 please post a comment!
